c# serializing an object to xml creates duplicate arrays
I have a class I want to serialize into xml to send to an API. This class has a list of packages but the xml is not generating as I would expect.
I want this, packages contains a list of package items:
<testRequest>
  <packages>
    <package>
      <id>1</id>
    </package>
    <package>
      <id>2</id>
    </package>
  </packages>
</testRequest>

But I am getting this, packages is generated once for each package item:
<TestRequest>
  <packages>
    <package>
      <id>1</id>
    </package>
  </packages>
  <packages>
    <package>
      <id>2</id>
    </package>
  </packages>
</TestRequest>

Here is the class:
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class TestRequest
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "packages")]
    public List<PackageRoot>? Packages { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class PackageRoot
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "package")]
    public MyPackage? Package { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class MyPackage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
}

and here is how I am serializing it:
private XmlDocument ConvertToXml(object o)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(writer, o);
    var xml = writer.ToString();
    writer.Close();
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    return doc;
}

To build the class:
var testRequest = new TestRequest() { Packages = [] };
var p1 = new MyPackage() { Id = "1" };
var p2 = new MyPackage() { Id = "2" };
testRequest.Packages.Add(new PackageRoot() { Package = p1 });
testRequest.Packages.Add(new PackageRoot() { Package = p2 });
var xmltestlRequest = ConvertToXml(testRequest);

I had it working before I added [XmlElement(ElementName = "xxx")] for the purpose of camelCasing the xml.
So really if there were a way to camelCase the xml without the attributes I could revert to that, but I would like to understand what is going wrong here.
Edit - My Resolution:
I removed all the ElementName tags (it cluttered everything up anyway) and I camel case the resultant xml string with a regex expression.

Try adding the attribute [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "package")] to the Packages property. It should keep it's original. XmlArrayItemAttribute
